# How to work-a-round with JSF annotation processing bug on Jetty?

Tags: jsf, maven, jetty, managed-bean

There's a bug in JSF loading mechanism for managed beans annotated with annotation *@ManagedBean*. The mechanism is not activated when running the app via **mvn jetty:run**. The bug is reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288243

This is a very nasty thing, because jetty:run have great advantages when debugging:

- it is fast
- it works directly with the jsf files from workspace, without need to use **FileSync** plugin

However, not supporting the annotation would require downgrading to XML configuration.

Is there any work-a-round for this bug?

Comment: but thats a strange bug in all. Any idea if its fixed in more recent version of jsf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source : the link you provided in your question , read Tomaz Lipinsi comments

> Hi, I've found a easy workaround for this problem. Actually I don't
>   use Jetty but Tomcat and Sysdeo Tomcat Launcher but it behaves the
>   same. JSF2 is looking for annotated classes in two places:
>   - WEB-INF/classes - so if the app is not packaged into .war, this directory does not exist
>   - classpath jars (WEB-INF/lib) - similar as above I've tried to override default com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider to my own so I
>   could provide him a list of my classes (see JavaDoc for this class).
>   While I was trying to do this then I hit upon an idea that I could
>   just simply put my compilled classes in WEB-INF/classes dir. Adding
>   this to pom.xml solved the problem: 
>   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
>    The drawback is that now I have compiled classes in source
>   dir but the most important is that it works.

Suggest you to read all the comments there.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, and it seems to work. My mind must have filtered such 'naughty' solution, but putting compilates to version-controlled src dir... well.... it hurts

Comment: @lechlukasz , yea it will but still it should be better then writing xml config ;)

Answer (score 1):

For avoid a mix between src and classes, you can set in your maven's POM some like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-project</finalName>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
 ....

</build>
```

And in the configuration of jetty's maven-plugin you can try this:
*Edit: Jetty's version used is 6.1.26*, if tag 'resources' doesn't work try 'resourcesAsCSV' instead

```
<configuration>
    ...
  <webAppConfig>
     <defaultsDescriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-NF/webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
     <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
          <resources>${basedir}/target/main/webapp,${basedir}/src/main/webapp</resources>
     </baseResource>
  </webAppConfig>
    ...
</configuration>
```

**Note: webdefault.xml is for setting an init-param needed for unblock files while jetty is running, the param is:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```